# Upcasting derived class to base class in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I am struggling to understand this scenario with casting.
For demo purposes I created these classes:

```
public interface IFoo {}
public class Foo : IFoo
{
      public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Bar : Foo
{
      public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my Main method I created a static method which returns IFoo:

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFoo iFoo = GetIFoo();
        Foo foo = (Foo)iFoo;           
       //the GetType ext method is executed and it returns Bar
       if(foo is Foo)
       {
            Console.WriteLine($"foo is of type: {foo.GetType()}");
       }
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static IFoo GetIFoo()
    {
         var bar = new Bar
         {
             Name = "MyName",
             Surname = "MySurname"
         }    
         return bar;
    }
}
```

The question is: even though I'm creating a Bar in the GetIFoo method why is it that if I'm casting the IFoo to Foo, foo's type is Bar and not Foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is it that if I'm casting the `iFoo` to `Foo`, `foo`'s type is `Bar` and not `Foo`?

This is because casting changes the static type. It has no effect on the dynamic type. `foo`'s *static* type is `Foo`, but its *dynamic* type is `Bar`.

Each variable has a type known to the compiler (*static type*) and a type known to the runtime (*dynamic type*). In some cases these two types are the same, but they do not have to be the same all the time.

Static type is the declared type of the variable. Dynamic type is what you get by calling `GetType` after an object is assigned to that variable.

You constructed an example when a static type of a variable does not match its dynamic type: `iFoo` has static type of `IFoo`, but its dynamic type is `Bar`. This is perfectly fine, because `Bar` is compatible with `IFoo`, because it implements the interface, and also with `Foo`, because it extends the class.

Comment: Is it possible to cast the dynamic type Bar to Foo at runtime?

Comment: Thank you, I've found the answer to my comment. This is exactly what I was looking to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is really [inheritance 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)): The object created is a `Bar` and casting just affects how you *view* it, not what it *truly is*.

Here you view it as an `IFoo`:

```
IFoo iFoo = GetIFoo();
```

And here you deliberately view it as a `Foo`. It it were not a `Foo`, or any of its descendants, you'd get a `InvalidCastException` on run-time.

```
Foo foo = (Foo)iFoo;
```

A `Bar` instance can legally be worked with as `Bar`, `Foo`, and `IFoo` (and as an `Object` for the sake of completeness). Regardless how you view the instance, it remains a `Bar`.

Comment: Meaning that the only way to get a Foo object is to specifically instantiate one then have a constructor that takes the necessary properties from another object?

Comment: @allencage Yes. Casting *doesn't* change (convert) the actual type of an object. Once you instantiate it like a `Bar`, it stays a `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

`Type.GetType` gives you the type of the underlying instance (i.e. the type you specify after `new`), no matter what type of variable holds it. Also, `foo is Foo` gives `true` not only if the actual instance is `Foo`, but for every type derived from `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Because with the line:

```
Foo foo = (Foo) iFoo;
```

you do *not* convert: a `Bar` is a `Foo` and an `IFoo` all at the same time. So when you cast to `(Foo)` the C# interpreter notices that `iFoo` is a `Bar` and thus leaves the object untouched. The point is, that from now on, the compiler will assume that `foo` is indeed a `Foo` object, but it can be of any class that extends the `Foo` class.

Let's make it more clear with the following example:

```
interface IDriveable {}  // IFoo
class Car : IDriveable { // Foo
    string Name {get; set; }
}
class Volkswagen : Car { // Bar
    bool CorrectPolution { get; set; }
}
```

Now if you construct a `Volkswagen`, ten obviously that is a `Car` and an `IDriveable`. But by saying: `Car car = (Car) volkswagen;`. You do *not* alter the volkswagen, you only now let the compiler know that `car` is a `Car` object.

Answer (score 1):

Because **GetType()** return type of object. When you explicity cast derived class to base class you didn't create a new instance, you only have new typed reference on existing object. You can see it with code below:

```
IFoo iFoo = GetIFoo();
Foo foo = (Foo)iFoo;
Console.WriteLine(ifoo.Equals(foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confused between the runtime-type of an object and its compile-time type.

```
IFoo iFoo = GetIFoo();
```

In the above line, `iFoo`'s runtime-type is still `Bar`. This is the real type of the object. But if you access the `Bar` object via a reference of type `IFoo` then the compiler only knows that the type is `IFoo`, hence called the compile-time type of the object pointed by reference `iFoo`. Note that the compiler lost this type information when the `return bar` statement in `GetIFoo` was executed.

```
Foo foo = (Foo)iFoo;
```

Further down, you can cast it to whatever type you want in the hierarchy of `Bar`, anything above and including `Bar` will succeed, and the compile time type will be based on what you type-casted it to. But again the runtime type will still stay the same i.e `Bar`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This makes things more clear. Is there another way of creating a Foo at runtime with this approach?

Comment: @allencage If you modify your method `GetIFoo` as follows `static IFoo GetIFoo() { var foo = new Foo { Name = "MyName" }; return foo; }` then your run-time-type and compile-time-type both would be `Foo`.